# Word VBA run action in footer only and not anywhere else

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

the following code is part of a much bigger piece of work (where it all works exactly as I wanted except this part).
I have a field in the footer with the document name and this takes the .doc/.docx off the end.
The problem is that it appears that this code also updates any links within the body of the document with the name of the document also e.g. if a link in the document is www.google.co.uk this macro will change that link on the document to the name of the document - I want this to only happen in the footer.

Can you please advise on how to get this code to do that? I have tried a few different things but none of them work.

```
        oldFilename = wdDocTgt.Name
         If Right(oldFilename, 5) = ".docx" Then
        oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 5)
        ElseIf Right(oldFilename, 4) = ".doc" Then
        oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 4)
 '       MsgBox (oldFilename)   'UNCOMMENT TO TEST

            'Updates all fields in the target document with the file name
 For Each aStory In wdDocTgt.StoryRanges
    For Each aField In aStory.Fields
    aField.Result.Text = oldFilename
        Next aField
        Next aStory
```

Comment: you will need to open the footer and then perform your steps.   ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it's addressing all parts of the document - which you don't want. You want only the footer(s). A Word document can have many footers, depending on how many sections the document has and whether the footers in the sections have been unlinked from previous sections. So if you wanted to check all the footers, you'd need to loop all the sections, something like

```
Dim sec as Word.Section
Dim rngFooter as Word.Range
For each sec in ActiveDocument.Sections
  Set rngFooter = sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  For each field in rngFooter.Fields
    aField.Result.Text = oldFilename
  Next field
Next sec
```

But keep in mind this will address *all* fields in the Footers, so it would end up affecting any Page numbers or Dates you might have...

There's another issue with the approach you're using: Field codes will update, and when they do, anything you've written to them, as you do in your code, will be lost. So you might be in for a very unpleasant surprise when you print this document, or when some other action triggers a field code update.

Since you aren't relying on the field code to generate the document name automatically, don't use a field code (whatever it might be). Delete the field code and use a bookmark, instead. Then you can assign the document name to the bookmark, something like this:

```
Dim rngBkm as Word.Range
Dim sBkmName as String
sBkmName = "DocName"
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(sBkmName) Then
  Set rngBkm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(sBkmName)
  rngBkm.Text = oldFileName
  'Assigning the text deletes the bookmark, so add it back
  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add sBkmName, rngBkm
End If
```

Note: I do NOT recommend you use the suggestion in Comments to open the Footer - no need to actually OPEN it and better not to.

Comment: Hi, how would I get the footer to include the DocName in the footer on page2 and 3 etc. I can only have one bookmark named DocName per document (correct me if I'm wrong)!

Comment: Well, if this is Word's Footer (and not just a position at the bottom of the page) then anything you put there will repeat throughout the document, on every page. That's the advantage of Headers and Footers :-) Things only get tricky if you don't want content on every page... If you don't want it on the *first* page, then you need to activate the "Different First Page" option in the document. (Note: this code will *not* write to a "different first page".)